# Access UIControls from Views outside the storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My view (in the `Main.storyboard`) contains another UIView which takes only about 80% of the screen's height (set with constraints).

In this second view (I call it the `viewContainer`) I want to display different views, which works with 
`viewContainer.bringSubview(toFront: someView)`

I created a new group in my project which contains 3 UIViewController classes and 3 xib files which I want to display in my `viewContainer`.

For each of those xib files I changed the background color to something unique so I can tell if it's working. And it does so far.

Now I tried adding a `UIButton` to the first `UIViewController` class and added an `@IBAction` for it. That just prints text to the console.

When I run the app I can switch between my 3 classes (3 different background colors) and I can also see and click the button I added to the first class when I select it.

But the code is never executed and my console is empty. Is that because my 3 other Views are not shown in my `Main.storyboard`?

[image: Project Structure Screenshot]

SimpleVC1.swift

```
import UIKit

class SimpleVC1: UIViewController {    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func onButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        print("test")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a target instead (and programmatically create the button), it might be easier:

```
import UIKit

class SimpleVC1: UIViewController {

    var button = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.frame.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        button.center = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        button.setTitle("Control 1", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(control1), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    }

    @objc func control1() {
        //Add your code for when the button is pressed here
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that I can't have controls in these UIVIewController classes I made? In the final application I want a lot of different controls in each view. Having all of them overlapping each other in my storyboard and hiding/showing them depending on the view being shown doesn't feel right

Comment: Yes, you can still have your controls. You just need to hide/show the controls whenever the view changes

Comment: I think you misunderstand. My button is not on my storyboard, but on my first of three classes. I bring each of those classes in front with the code above which automatically shows the class I want at a time (and hides the other including the controls on them). The problem is rather that the actions on those controls don't work

Comment: So you can see the button, but the code isn't being fired when you press it?

Comment: Exactly. I added a screenshot of the structure to my initial post.

Comment: Are you using a target to run the code when the button is pressed?

Comment: I edited the post and added the code of my first class

Comment: Tried that. Put a print("test") inside the function. Still no output on the console though. The button is visible though and viewDidLoad() gets called

Comment: Maybe try something else that happens when you press the button?

Comment: Tried changing the buttons title. Didn't work either. It's not the the print-command failing

Comment: Did you ctrl-drag to the `IBAction` so the button's target is that method? You could also try to set it programmatically: `button.addTarget(self, #selector(onButtonPressed:), for: .touchUpInside)`